# How do I search through multiple Tumblr pages for a word all at once?

Tags: tumblr

I want to know how to span through multiple pages at once looking for one word. So say I wanted to find the word "bear", it would essentially look through this person's entire tumblr for the word.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing you can try is to simply Google it.

For example, say you wanted to find out when Horses were added to Minecraft. You could [search for `site:mcupdate.tumblr.com horse`](https://www.google.com/#q=site%3Amcupdate.tumblr.com%20horse).

Answer (score 0):

Tumblr blogs have a search function, even if it is not shown.

```
http://example.tumblr.com/search/foo
```

Replace `example` with the Tumblr blog name, and replace `foo` with the keyword you want to search for.

(This might not work in all cases, though.)